# Laravel 4 : getting json from database tables

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, jsonp

I have tables festivals, addressess and locations. A festival has one address and a address has one location. Now I want to get json from these 3 tables with laravel. At the moment I get festivals and addresses. How to retrieve the 3th table locations?

```
public function json()
        {
            $festival = Festival::with('address')->get();

            return Response::json(array('festivals' => $festival))->setCallback(Input::get('callback'));

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eager load nested relationships:

```
$festival = Festival::with('address.location')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get relationships via eager loading using comma separated values in the with() method, like so:

```
$festivals = Festival::with('address', 'address.location')->get();
```

Hope this helps.